# how do i check if a variable is a certain pyspark.sql.SparkSession function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark, pytest

pyspark 2.3.1, python 3.5.6, osx high sierra.

i need variable pyspark load methods, so i'm passing functions to a function. when writing unit tests, is it possible to test that `var==pyspark.read.json`, for instance?

by the way, i already tried:

```
>> spark = pyspark.sql.SparkSession
>> foo = spark.read.json
>> foo == spark.read.json
False
```

Comment: this is kind of useless... but if you want to compare names of functions you can use `__name__`: `spark.read.json.__name__`. What would you want to test? it's better to mock spark context or feed it with fixtures so you can test your transformations

Comment: if i were to mock, i would have to mock each load function that might get called... this might be more reasonable, as digging into the `__name__` attribute would require some rework anyway. thanks for the input!